# Nested loops Imacros

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to make an Imacros that contains 2 loops, but I can't seem to figure it out. It should first extract data from a csv file and submit it x times to mywebsite, then extract x URLs from another csv file and click y number of times on a link. I can't find any method to have to loops without using javascript, and I can't use that since I have absolutely zero knowledge about it. This is what I got so far:

```
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://mywebsite.com
SET !DATASOURCE infos.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 5
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:Name FORM=ID:sm ATTR=ID:sl CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:age FORM=ID:iD ATTR=ID:sD CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:heigh FORM=ID:sf ATTR=ID:lf CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:nationality FORM=ID:sfw ATTR=ID:sfq CONTENT={{!COL4}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:send
URL GOTO=https://www.mywebsite.com/{{!COL5}}
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=I ATTR=TXT:Jump <-- This is the 2nd loop  -->
```

as an exemple, when I set the imacros play loop to 10, that should be assigned to the 1st loop.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this maybe:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var macro = "CODE";
    macro +="URL GOTO=https://mywebsite.com" + "\n";
    macro +="SET !DATASOURCE infos.csv" + "\n";
    macro +="SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 5"" + "\n";
    macro +="SET !LOOP 2" "\n";
    macro +="SET !DATASOURCE_LINE" + i + "\n";
    ....

    iimPlay(macro);
    for (var j = 0; i < 10; j++)
    {
        var macro2 = "CODE";
        macro2 += "TAG POS=" + j + "TYPE=I ATTR=TXT:Jump";
        iimPlay(macro2);
    }        
}
```

So basically you define a macro string and then use `iimPlay()` method to play it. Make sure you create a Javascript file and run it (press only Play button no Play Loop).

Every string should have `"CODE:"` in it to start off. Then adding a new line after every line of iMacros code.

Pretty much for the `{{LOOP}}` just change it to the loop variable.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question if you do not mind, I can't find the answer anywhere. The TAG POS=X, X being a random number, I tried POS=* but it's not working, any idea how I could make it work?

Comment: I'm not too much of an expert at this sorry. I don't believe the * works with Tag Pos. I'm pretty sure you are allowed to ask this question again but just post the new code and any problems. Hope it helped though

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that with regular imacros as it does not support loop inside loop or 2 different loops inside one script. use javascript or similar.

Comment: How would I proceed using Javascript? I have no knowledge about it whatsoever so I would really appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: there is huge amount of javascript looping code examples on this site. use search

Comment: Or you can visit his or mine profile and check the answers. There are tons of answers a bout iMacros.

Comment: This could've been a comment. This is not an answer on the OP their question. Please take a look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer